# Custom Navigation Icon not visible Material Toolbar Android

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, material-components

I am using Material Design Components, each fragment in my app has a seperate Toolbar [Fragment Owned Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/appbar#fragment)

I am having issue setting the custom drawable as the navitaion icon using xml attribute.
In the [Material.io docs](https://material.io/components/app-bars-top/android#regular-top-app-bar) they mention a xml attribute to set the custom navitaion icon.
Navigation Icon is not visible on the screen? what did I miss?

**xml attribute mentioned in docs**

```
app:navigationIcon="@customDrawable"
```

**Reference Image from Material.io Appbar Docs**

[image: Material Toolbar Docs Reference Image]

**My fragment_home.xml**

```
   <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu"
                app:title="@null" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

**Navigation Icon Not Visible**

[image: Mobile Screenshot]

Comment: Are you using the Navigation Components ?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes